# How to solve transcendental equations with MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, numerical-optimization, transcendental-equations

Here's the equation:

$$ - \frac{MN}{\sqrt{2\pi \left( \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 \right)}} \frac d {dy} \exp \left( -\frac {y^2} {\left( \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 \right)} \right) = k \left( x-y \right) $$

About the equation(s):
The equation on the left side models an attraction force, the one on the right hand side a spring force. The parameters $ M, N, \sigma_1, \sigma_2 $ and $ k $ do not change. $ x $ is the *distance* to the initial position (fixed value, doesn't change) and $ y $ is the *distance* to the position (I'm looking for) where both forces are balanced.
I already tried **solve**, but that didn't really help me. I also read, that it should be solved numerically, but I don't really know how to do this in Matlab.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you want to find $y=f(x)$?

Comment: No I don't, $ x $ is just the starting value and does not change (sorry, I forgot to highlight this in my description), I want to find the solution of $ f \left( y \right) = f \left( y \right) $. I need to find the point $ y $ (or distance) where both forces are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ease of notation let
$$a = -\frac{MN}{k\sqrt{2\pi(\sigma_{1}^{2} + \sigma_{2}^{2})}}$$
and
$$b = (\sigma_{1}^{2}+\sigma_{2}^{2}).$$
Then we would like to find $y$ such that
$$- 2 y \frac{a}{b} \exp[-y^{2}/b] = x - y.$$
Equivalently, we would like to find the root of $f(y)$, where
$$f(y) = y - 2y\frac{a}{b}\exp[-y^{2}/b] - x.$$

There are a number of ways to find roots numerically e.g. [the bisection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method), [secant method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method) or [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

I suggest you don't implement any of these yourself: rather just use MATLAB's `fzero` command - [read its documentation here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html).